# how to remove specific key from multidimension array

Tags: php, arrays

### This is what the result i need to come out with

```
"data": [
        {
        "ticket_category_id": "677",
        "ticket_category_name": " Testing 500",
        "ticket_category_order": "1",
        "tickets": 
                [
                {
                "ticket_id": "927",
                "ticket_title": "EDI Project Template with attachments",
                "ticket_order": "1",
                "due_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                "created_date": "2018-05-16 10:01:04",
                "edited_date": "2018-05-17 02:56:38",
                "updated_date": "2018-05-17 02:56:38",
                "is_complete": "0",
                "total_comment": "0",
                "total_attachment": "10",
                "total_checklist_items": "48",
                "total_completed_checklist_items": "0",
                "label": [
                         {
                        "ticket_label_name": "",
                        "ticket_color_code": "#FF3B30"
                    },
                    "#D4891C": {
                        "ticket_label_name": "IN PROGRESS",
                        "ticket_color_code": "#D4891C"
                    }]
                },
                "people": []
            },
            {
                "ticket_id": "928",
                "ticket_title": "EDI Project Template",
                "ticket_order": "2",
                "due_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                "created_date": "2018-05-16 10:01:04",
                "edited_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                "updated_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                "is_complete": "0",
                "total_comment": "0",
                "total_attachment": "0",
                "total_checklist_items": "48",
                "total_completed_checklist_items": "0",
                "label": [
                         {
                        "ticket_label_name": "",
                        "ticket_color_code": "#4CD964"
                    }]
                },
                "people": []
            }
           ]
```

But what i get the result is like below

```
 {
    "data": [
        {
            "ticket_category_id": "677",
            "ticket_category_name": " Testing 500",
            "ticket_category_order": "1",
            "tickets": {
                "927": {
                    "ticket_id": "927",
                    "ticket_title": "EDI Project Template with attachments",
                    "ticket_order": "1",
                    "due_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "created_date": "2018-05-16 10:01:04",
                    "edited_date": "2018-05-17 02:56:38",
                    "updated_date": "2018-05-17 02:56:38",
                    "is_complete": "0",
                    "total_comment": "0",
                    "total_attachment": "10",
                    "total_checklist_items": "48",
                    "total_completed_checklist_items": "0",
                    "label": {
                        "#FF3B30": {
                            "ticket_label_name": "",
                            "ticket_color_code": "#FF3B30"
                        }
                    },
                    "people": []
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "ticket_category_id": "677",
            "ticket_category_name": " Testing 500",
            "ticket_category_order": "1",
            "tickets": {
                "927": {
                    "ticket_id": "927",
                    "ticket_title": "EDI Project Template with attachments",
                    "ticket_order": "1",
                    "due_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "created_date": "2018-05-16 10:01:04",
                    "edited_date": "2018-05-17 02:56:38",
                    "updated_date": "2018-05-17 02:56:38",
                    "is_complete": "0",
                    "total_comment": "0",
                    "total_attachment": "10",
                    "total_checklist_items": "48",
                    "total_completed_checklist_items": "0",
                    "label": {
                        "#D4891C": {
                            "ticket_label_name": "IN PROGRESS",
                            "ticket_color_code": "#D4891C"
                        }
                    },
                    "people": []
                }
            }
        },
```

And below is the code I have done, I using php mysql one to many relationship get all the data to be flat array, and then below code is convert single flat array into three multidimension array, but i meet a bottleneck. Please help to review my code to point out which part I need to change to become my expected result.

```
  $result = array();
    foreach($total_count as $Key => $Value){
        $ticketCatId = $Value['ticket_category_id'];
        $ticketId = $Value['ticket_id'];
        $ticketColorCode = $Value['ticket_color_code'];
        $ticketMember = $Value['user_id'];
    
        $result[$ticketCatId]['ticket_category_id'] = $Value['ticket_category_id'];
        $result[$ticketCatId]['ticket_category_name'] = $Value['ticket_category_name'];
        $result[$ticketCatId]['ticket_category_order']  = $Value['ticket_category_order'];

        if(!isset($result[$ticketCatId]['tickets'])) {
            $result[$ticketCatId]['tickets'] = array();
        }

        // this code is append the ticket ID
        if($ticketId && !isset($result[$ticketCatId]['tickets'][$ticketId])) {
            $ticket = array(
                'ticket_id'                         => $Value['ticket_id'],
                'ticket_title'                      => $Value['ticket_title'],
                'ticket_order'                      => $Value['ticket_order'],
                'due_date'                          => $Value['due_date'],
                'created_date'                      => $Value['created_date'],
                'edited_date'                       => $Value['edited_date'],
                'updated_date'                      => $Value['updated_date'],
                'is_complete'                       => $Value['is_complete'],
                'total_comment'                     => $Value['total_comment'],
                'total_attachment'                  => $Value['total_attachment'],
                'total_checklist_items'             => $Value['total_checklist_items'],
                'total_completed_checklist_items'   => $Value['total_completed_checklist_items'],
                'label' => array(),
                'people' => array()
                
            );
            $result[$ticketCatId]['tickets'][$ticketId] = $ticket;
        }

        if($ticketColorCode && isset($result[$ticketCatId]['tickets'][$ticketId]) && !isset($result[$ticketCatId]['tickets'][$ticketId]['label'][$ticketColorCode])) {
            $ticketColor = array(
                'ticket_label_name' => $Value['ticket_label_name'],
                'ticket_color_code' => $Value['ticket_color_code']
            );
            $result[$ticketCatId]['tickets'][$ticketId]['label'][$ticketColorCode] = $ticketColor;
        }

        if($ticketMember && isset($result[$ticketCatId]['tickets'][$ticketId]) && !isset($result[$ticketCatId]['tickets'][$ticketId]['people'][$ticketMember])) {
            $ticketPeople = array(
                'user_id' => $Value['user_id'],
                'photo' => $Value['photo']
            );
            $result[$ticketCatId]['tickets'][$ticketId]['people'][$ticketMember] = $ticketPeople;
        }
}

    dd(json_encode(["data"=>$result]));
```

Comment: Instead of specifying the indexes of `$result` based on the value of `$ticketCatId`, allow PHP to generate the indexes automatically. Aggregate all of the data to be added into a temporary array, and then just do `$result[] = $tmpArray;`

Comment: Hi @PatrickQ i am new on the php array, can you please give me the example code as your describe above? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any sample data to work with, so I can't actually test this for you.  The general idea though is that each time through the loop, you initialize a temporary array (`$tmpArray = array();`) and put all the loop-specific values into that array.  Then, at the end of each loop iteration, you push that temporary array onto your `$results` array (`$result[] = $tmpArray;`), allowing PHP to automatically create sequential indexes for `$results`.  The reason why you are getting nested JSON objects currently is because `json_encode()` will only produce JSON arrays from sequentially-index PHP arrays

```
  $result = array();
    foreach($total_count as $Key => $Value){
        $ticketCatId = $Value['ticket_category_id'];
        $ticketId = $Value['ticket_id'];
        $ticketColorCode = $Value['ticket_color_code'];
        $ticketMember = $Value['user_id'];

        $tmpArray = array();

        $tmpArray['ticket_category_id'] = $Value['ticket_category_id'];
        $tmpArray['ticket_category_name'] = $Value['ticket_category_name'];
        $tmpArray['ticket_category_order']  = $Value['ticket_category_order'];

        if(!isset($tmpArray['tickets'])) {
            $tmpArray['tickets'] = array();
        }

        // this code is append the ticket ID
        if($ticketId && !isset($tmpArray['tickets'][$ticketId])) {
            $ticket = array(
                'ticket_id'                         => $Value['ticket_id'],
                'ticket_title'                      => $Value['ticket_title'],
                'ticket_order'                      => $Value['ticket_order'],
                'due_date'                          => $Value['due_date'],
                'created_date'                      => $Value['created_date'],
                'edited_date'                       => $Value['edited_date'],
                'updated_date'                      => $Value['updated_date'],
                'is_complete'                       => $Value['is_complete'],
                'total_comment'                     => $Value['total_comment'],
                'total_attachment'                  => $Value['total_attachment'],
                'total_checklist_items'             => $Value['total_checklist_items'],
                'total_completed_checklist_items'   => $Value['total_completed_checklist_items'],
                'label' => array(),
                'people' => array()

            );
            $tmpArray['tickets'][$ticketId] = $ticket;
        }

        if($ticketColorCode && isset($tmpArray['tickets'][$ticketId]) && !isset($tmpArray['tickets'][$ticketId]['label'][$ticketColorCode])) {
            $ticketColor = array(
                'ticket_label_name' => $Value['ticket_label_name'],
                'ticket_color_code' => $Value['ticket_color_code']
            );
            $tmpArray['tickets'][$ticketId]['label'][$ticketColorCode] = $ticketColor;
        }

        if($ticketMember && isset($tmpArray['tickets'][$ticketId]) && !isset($tmpArray['tickets'][$ticketId]['people'][$ticketMember])) {
            $ticketPeople = array(
                'user_id' => $Value['user_id'],
                'photo' => $Value['photo']
            );
            $tmpArray['tickets'][$ticketId]['people'][$ticketMember] = $ticketPeople;
        }

        $result[] = $tmpArray;
}

    dd(json_encode(["data"=>$result]));
```

Comment: I have test the code, it not what i want the result. After apply the code, group by ticketid & the ticket_category_id not working already.

Comment: I am not able to understand what you are saying. Can you update your question to show the new results?

Comment: I have updated the result above, please have a look, ticket_category_id should only appear 1 time but now is repeating, same as ticket ID.

Comment: Wait, do you have multiple rows in `$total_count` that have the same `ticket_category_id`, and you want all of those rows _merged_ by `ticket_category_id`?

Comment: @JASONWONG8  Also, the example that you say you need to get is not valid JSON. You have a key (`"#D4891C": {`) on your second color entry in the first ticket. That can't be there.

Comment: yes, $total_count is one to many relationship query, ticket_category_id & ticket_id is repeated, i need to merge it based on ticket_category_id & also ticket_id.